# Target the next element with different class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have list of buttons similar to this one:

```
<a href="#" class="btn green">Button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn green">Button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn red">Button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn red">Button</a>
```

The number of buttons can vary. I want to select the first red button and change its class from red to blue so the list will look like:

```
<a href="#" class="btn green">Button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn green">Button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn blue">Button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn red">Button</a>
```

How to achieve that?

Comment: Add your current attempt.

Comment: Remember, StackOverflow is here to help, but we are **not** a code-writing service. Have you tried to solve this yourself before asking here?  Step 1: *"select the first red button"* Step 2: *"change its class"*. You can likely find your answer if you break it out into steps.

Answer (score -1):

With JQuery:
grab all of the elements with "red" class
then select the first one and remove it's red class and add the blue class

```js
$($(".red")[0]).removeClass("red").addClass("blue");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
.green{color: green;}
.red{color: red;}
.blue{color: blue;}
</style>
<a href="#" class="btn green">Button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn green">Button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn red">Button</a>
<a href="#" class="btn red">Button</a>
```